Flutter Firebase Messaging: Handling Data Messages When App is Terminated(Killed)
I'm developing a chat application in Flutter using Firebase Cloud Messaging (FCM) to send notifications. The notifications are sent from the server as data messages, not as notification messages.
Server-Side Code
Here's how I'm sending the notification from the server:
const message = {
    token: deviceToken,
    data: {
        senderName: senderName,
        message: messageContent,
        conversationId: conversationId,
        companyId: companyId,
        isGroup: 'false'
    }
}

Client-Side Code:
On the client side, I have set up the following to handle notifications:

Background Message Handler:

Future<void> backgroundHandler(RemoteMessage message) async {
    // Handle background message
    LocalNotificationService.display(message);
}



Main Initialization:

Future<void> main() async {
    WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
    await Firebase.initializeApp();
    FirebaseMessaging.onBackgroundMessage(backgroundHandler);
    runApp(MyApp());
}


Handling in Root app's Init:

 void initState() {
    super.initState();
    print("Inside Init");

    // Initialize local notification service
    LocalNotificationService.initialize();

    // Listen for messages when the app is in the foreground
    FirebaseMessaging.onMessage.listen((message) {
      print('Foreground message received: ${message.messageId}');
      if (message.data.isNotEmpty) {
        print('Displaying Message');
        LocalNotificationService.display(message);
      }
    });

    // Check for initial message when the app is launched
    handleInitialMessage();
  }

  Future<void> handleInitialMessage() async {
    RemoteMessage? initialMessage =
        await FirebaseMessaging.instance.getInitialMessage();
    if (initialMessage != null) {
      Fluttertoast.showToast(
          msg: 'Inside Handle get initial message ${initialMessage.data}');
      if (initialMessage.data.isNotEmpty) {
        handleRemoteMessage(initialMessage);
      } else if (initialMessage.notification != null) {
        Fluttertoast.showToast(msg: 'Notification caused app launch');
      } else {
        Fluttertoast.showToast(msg: 'No data in initial message');
      }
    } else {
      Fluttertoast.showToast(msg: 'No initial message received');
    }
  }

  void handleRemoteMessage(RemoteMessage message) {
    // Extract and handle the message data
    Map<String, dynamic> data = message.data;
    final String companyId = data['companyId'];
    final String conversationId = data['conversationId'];
    final bool isGroup = data['isGroup'] == 'true';

    User? currentUser = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser;
    if (currentUser != null) {
      String email = currentUser.email ?? '';
      String employeeEmail = email.split('-')[1];

      fetchEmployeeIdFromFirestore(
        incomingCompanyId: companyId,
        employeeEmail: employeeEmail,
      ).then((fetchedCompanyId) {
        if (fetchedCompanyId != null) {
          Navigator.pushNamed(
            navigatorKey.currentState!.context,
            '/ChatScreen',
            arguments: {
              'companyId': companyId,
              'employeeId': fetchedCompanyId,
              'conversationId': conversationId,
              'isGroup': isGroup,
            },
          );
        } else {
          print('Error: Employee email not found');
        }
      });
    } else {
      Navigator.pushNamed(navigatorKey.currentState!.context, '/LoginScreen');
    }
  }


Issue
When the app is terminated(killed) and a user taps on a notification, message.data is null. This prevents the app from navigating to the appropriate screen.

But When I trigger A dummy notification from firebase i'm getting empty {} Map

Question
How can I ensure that the data message is properly handled when the app is terminated(killed), so the app can navigate correctly when a user taps on the notification?

Any guidance or examples on how to handle this scenario would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

To solve this problem I stored messages in local database and listen via stream on UI. So, now if I received a notification in background/killed state, I just put that message in my local database and when the user click on notification. I get the chat_page/id and navigate to the particular chat and the message is visible on the chat screen.

Oh Could you please Explain it in detail

it's like the local database is preferred in my case. Suppose  I am sending a message to other user then it'll go into my local db then on the server. and for notification I have used a custom api created in dart. Which internally using http to send the notification to firebase. So, at receiver side when the message is received in killed state. I just put that message into local database and show the notification. Now that receiver can tap on that notification and navigate to that particular chat page and the message is already stored in local database so it'll visible on chat page.

based on my understanding, I am doing exactly the same. I used Node.js on the server side to trigger notifications as data messages. I implemented it similarly to how you described. Instead of using an HTTP trigger, I use the onCreate Cloud Function event to send notifications. However, when I use getInitialMessage, it returns null.

So, I think the problem is with the node.js api. Can you paste that in your question?

Yes First block of in my question is that code and i have one more doubt
if you are storing your Message in your Local storage How would the Receiver know about it?
Could you please explain about it

I used isar database in flutter. So when the chat page is opened i am listening the query which is working like stream. So, I am showing the message in the notification and also storing the message in isar database. and when user just open the chat page the message will be visible.
